Fail to reproduce the result when using a shared modules for different models by pytorch
I'm trying to train two neural networks and they're both based on transformer architecture.
The output of the first model becomes the input for the second model, and each loss is integrated to update both model as follows, which is reproduced without any issue:
random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed) 
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic=True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark=False
os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = str(seed)
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)

model1 = my_model1()
model2 = my_model2()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(list(model1.parameters()) + list(model2.parameters()),lr=0.0001)

for x,y,z in dataloader:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output1 = model1(x)
    output2 = model2(output1)
    loss1 = criterion1(output1, y)
    loss2 = criterion2(output2, z)
    total_loss = loss1 + loss2
    total_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

However, I want to share the projection parameters of attention layers of the two models, but in this case the result is not reproduced.
random.seed(seed)
torch.manual_seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed) 
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic=True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark=False
os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = str(seed)
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)


shared_modules=[] # here is the shared qkv parameters
for i in range(layers):
    query_projection = torch.nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
    key_projection = torch.nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
    value_projection = torch.nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
    shared_modules.append([query_projection, key_projection, value_projection])
     
model1 = my_model1(shared_modules)
model2 = my_model2(shared_modules) 

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(list(model1.parameters()) + list(model2.parameters()),lr=0.0001)

for x,y,z in dataloader:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output1 = model1(x)
    output2 = model2(output1)
    loss1 = criterion1(output1, y)
    loss2 = criterion2(output2, z)
    total_loss = loss1 + loss2
    total_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

I tried to debug it, and I found out that the gradients after "total_loss.backward()", and updated parameter values after "optimizer.step()" of the two models are reproduced in the first batch.
However, in the second batch, the updated parameter values after "optimizer.step()" are not reproduced, while the gradients before "optimizer.step()" is reproduced.
Also, when I run the model on cpu, the results are reproduced always.
What I expect to be the issue is that there is some kind of non-deterministic function in "optimizer.step()" that determines the order of the gradients from model1 and model2, but I'm not sure about it.
What can be the cause of different result only when using shared parameters?
